# How to return a null value after destructuring?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator, destructuring

I am trying to show and hide text based on a user's permission which is destructed from a user object which has the name, email and many more.

I have tried setting a null value to the permissions array but it is still not working

```
<User>
    {({
      data: {
        me: { permissions = "" }
      }
    }) => (
      <div>
        {permissions === null && <p>Welcome stranger</p>}
        {permissions === "USER" && <p>welcome dear user</p>}
        {permissions === "ADMIN" && <p>Welcome Dear Admin</p>}
      </div>
    )}
  </User>
```

Comment: can you include some code that shows what you are doing? you description is vague at best

Comment: you're setting permissions to `""` not `null` ... so check for `""` or set to `null` .... and where is the `permissions array` I see no array

Comment: this is what my graphql looks like in the backend `type User {
 id: ID!
 name: String!
 email: String!
 permissions: [Permission!]!
 cart: [CartItem!]!
}`

Comment: in my frontend i am querying this data using a User component

Answer (score 0):

You're settings `permissions` to `""`, so either check for `""` *and* `null`, or set `permissions` to `null`.

First option:

```
{(permissions === null || permissions === "") && <p>Welcome stranger!</p>}
```

Second option:

```
me: { permissions: null }
```